# Including a private pod as a dependency of another private pod in .podspec file

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, dependency-management

I have 2 private pods. Let's call them `PrivateA` and `PrivateB`. These used to not depend on each other, so I could use them both in my project pretty easily like so:

```
source 'http://my-private-domain.com/PrivateA.git'
source 'http://my-private-domain.com/PrivateB.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'MyProject' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyProject
  pod 'PrivateA', :git => 'http://my-private-domain.com/PrivateA.git'
  pod 'PrivateB', :git => 'http://my-private-domain.com/PrivateB.git'
  pod 'lottie-ios', '1.2.1'
end
```

Now, I realize that `Private A` should start depending on `PrivateB`. Since both of them are private pods, I'm not sure how to modify `PrivateA.podspec` to make this happen. Here's what I tried in `PrivateA.podspec`:

```
s.source = {
  :git => "http://my-private-domain.com/PrivateA.git",
  :git => "http://my-private-domain.com/PrivateB.git"
}

s.dependency "PrivateB"
```

This is the error I'm getting when trying to `pod spec lint` my PrivateA pod:

```
ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Unable to find a specification for `PrivateB` depended upon by `PrivateA`) during validation.
```

Please help!

Comment: Any answer on this? @7ball

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to add this option after `pod spec lint`

```
--sources='http://my-private-domain.com/PrivateA.git,http://my-private-domain.com/PrivateB.git,https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```