# How to use a private pod as a dependency in the podspec of another pod?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have 2 private pods in my pod specs repository, let's say `Pod1` and `Pod2`.

I want to include `Pod2` as a dependency of `Pod1`, so I tried adding this line in `Pod1.podspec`:

```
spec.dependency 'Pod2', '~> 1.0.2'
```

Then, I tried linting my pod with a `pod spec lint`, and got this error:

> ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Unable to find a specification for Pod2 (~> 1.0.2) depended upon by Pod1

After a few research, I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46738672/including-a-private-pod-as-a-dependency-of-another-private-pod-in-podspec-file) on SO recommending to specify the sources on the lint command:

```
pod spec lint --sources='{MY_POD1_REPO_URL.git, MY_POD2_REPO_URL.git}'
```

Now, I'm getting this error instead:

> - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (An unexpected version directory Classes was encountered for the /Users/me/.cocoapods/repos/bitbucket-pod2.repo/Pod2 Pod in the Pod2 repository.) during validation.

What should I do? Thank you for your help.

Comment: in your pod file fill the source of private pod source 'https://github.com/YourCustomPod/Specs.git'

Comment: maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44842837/podfile-path-of-local-pod-relative-to-projectpath-possible/44855971#44855971

Comment: Thank you for your answers but there is something I'm missing... I don't have a Podfile yet, only a framework and a library, each of them exported as a Pod with their .podspec file. So I don't understand in which Podfile I'd be supposed to add this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `--include-podspecs=` option like

`pod lib lint --include-podspecs=\{Pod2.podspec\} Pod1.podspec`

There's a script for finding all podspecs in the same directory and adding them to the `pod lib lint` line [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/scripts/pod_lib_lint.rb).